# Codeception runShellCommand not failing test when Laravel artisan throws a fatal error

Tags: laravel, codeception, laravel-artisan

I am running a codeception test with the following directive:

```
$I->runShellCommand('php artisan <custom command>');
```

The artisan command currently throws a PHP Fatal Error because a class was not found.  That is fine.  I know how to fix it.  However, codeception is not picking up that the command failed.  The test passes when it should not.

A few things of note:

- When I run the custom artisan command directly in a shell, the exit code is 255
- Using

  ```
  $I->runShellCommand('php artisan <custom command>'); 
  $I->seeInShellOutput('error');`
  ```

  fails with the message

  ```
  Step  I see in shell output "error"
  Fail  Failed asserting that '' contains "error".
  ```

  (Why is codeception not seeing any output when the command is producing an error?)
- Using

  ```
  $I->runShellCommand('php artisan up'); 
  $I->seeInShellOutput('error');
  ```

  fails as expected with the message

  ```
  Step  I see in shell output "error"
  Fail  Failed asserting that 'Application is now live.' contains "error".
  ```

  (Codeception is obviously seeing the output for a command that is not erroring out.)
- When I find the runShellCommand method in the Codeception source code and add `die(var_dump($resultCode))` to the method, I see that the result code that codeception is seeing is in fact 0.  So why is Codeception not seeing the fatal error that I do when I run the command directly?

Any idea what's going on here?  How can I get my artisan command tests to fail if the artisan commands are failing due to a PHP Fatal error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the reason you're seeing this is two fold:

1. Artisan commands are wrapped in a try / catch block. You can see this in **Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php** in the method **handle**. Because of this, the PHP engine's exception that is thrown would never be passed beyond Laravel's handler. When Laravel catches one of these exceptions, it hands off the response to Symphony's console renderer, which returns an array in the following format:

   Array
   (
     [0] => 
     [1] => 
     [2] =>   [Exception Name]
     [3] =>   Text description.
     [4] => 
     [5] => 
   )

Now, when the a console command is used via either `exec` or `shell`, if the result is an array it will output the first index only unless it is handled in a special way; like print_r. In this case, that's an empty value.

2. The second issue may be that both `exec` and `shell` cause a new thread to spawn. If there is an error on the newly spawned thread, Codeception wouldn't be able to catch anything.

There's no guide in the docs for testing kernel commands from the command line. I believe it's more recommended to test the classes used in a command directly. However, if you'd really like to test the entire thing, you can always make an instance of the **Kernel.php** class listed above and run commands directly through the `call` method, rather than the `handle` method.